# Find specific position in matrix

Tags: algorithms, matrix

Consider a binary (i.e. over $\{0, 1\}$) matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ of size $n \times n$. It is known that there is *exactly one* $r \in [1; n]$ such that $a_{rj} = 0$ for all $j \in [1; n]$ and $a_{ir} = 1$ for all $i \in [1; n] \setminus \{r\}$. How to find $r$ asymptotically in $O(n)$ in terms of time?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this question?

Comment: Can you give some motivation for this question? For example, please define your notation like $[1;n]$. Also, please state the $a_{rj} = 0$ condition is trying to capture in words rather than just notation so it is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $i \neq j$.

- If $a_{ij} = 0$ then $j \neq r$ (why?).
- If $a_{ij} = 1$ then $i \neq r$ (why?).

You take it from here.